# How to put a check on home directory shortcut ~ given through CLI in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, input, filesystems, command-line-interface

I want to put a check on home directory shortcut `~` given as a parameter to an input option through CLI in a **C** program running on **Linux**.

The shortcut is converted into the full path before it is read from a `main()` function argument.

I added following literal check on it but it does not work, as the parameter has been replaced with the home directory full path (like `/home/myself`) by CLI.

```
if ((strstr(pName, (const char *)"~/") != NULL) || (strcmp((const char *)pName, (const char *)"~") == 0))
{
    /* home directory shortcut is not allowed/;
}
```

How can I add a literal check which disallows the user to enter home directory shortcut (not full path), or how to make sure the CLI does not convert the shortcut into path?

Please note that, if the user explicitly enters the home directory path as input parameter, then that is fine. I only need to put a check on the shortcut.

**Some background:**

It is just one of the security checks, not allowing the user to access privileged locations. The user will be accessing the application through a web interface and the application will be running in a space (/home/main) other than what is allocated to the user (/home/user_1)

Comment: What do you want to do that for?

Comment: Just one of the security checks, not allowing the user to access privileged locations. The user will be accessing the application through a web interface and the application will be running in a space (/home/main) other than what is allocated to the user (/home/user_1).

Comment: Then why don't you compare the directory with `/home/main` instead of checking for tilde expansion?

Comment: @FUZxxl The requirement is to restrict shortcut ~ (without the knowledge that it gets converted into home directory). Now, it seems impossible to do.

Comment: I fail to see how there is a security problem with `~` expansion.  If the user can type `/home/user_1` and get the same results, there is **no** security problem - the user has the same permissions either way.

Comment: /home/user_1 is allowed, as it is the allocated space to the user. /home/main may not be allowed, so it should not be accessible to the user by any means. ~ shortcut is making it accessible. (suppose the user does not know what ~ will expand to).

Comment: @ZeeshanMahmood How is `~` making that accessible? If your code prohibits access to `/home/main`, access will be denied even when `/home/main` is accessed through `~`; remember, your code is only ever going to see what `~` expands to. Anyway, if you want to restrict file access, consider using a mechanism like jails for that instead of trying to rig something that breaks easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` is expanded to `$HOME` by the shell, not by your application. Your application has no way of finding out if `~` expansion happened, i.e. you cannot distinguish if the user typed

```
application ~/foo
```

or

```
application /home/me/foo
```

Comment: So, there is no solution for this problem?

Comment: @ZeeshanMahmood No, there isn't. Why is that a problem any way? Why are you interested in forbidding the user from using `~` expansion?

Comment: See "some background" in the question above. I just edited it.

Comment: FUZxxl - Another part of the question is, can we disallow ~ expansion (through application)?

Comment: @ZeeshanMahmood The application cannot disallow `~` expansion. In some shells you can turn off `~` expansion, but I don't know how to do that in bash (the standard Linux shell). Consider taking the paths in a different way, e.g. from a configuration file or from standard input to not have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will look into it from different angle now. At least the reported question is answered - not possible. :)